# Displaying Analytics Dashboard for Clients using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

We have certain amount of clients and each of us will have their pages on our website. We have to show them the analytics for their particular page. For this, we have the data on Google Analytics according to pages.

On the client admin page, they should be able to view the analytics for their page. This has to be coming from Google Analytics.

I have tried using the Core Reporting Api, but that needs an authentication and one should have access to Google Analytics profile, which is not possible for clients.

So now, Is there a way, where the client can see the dashboard with data being pulled form Google Analytics without any authentication?

Comment: Are you using a master google analytics account?  Or do each of your customers have their own individual accounts (and you insert their tracking code for them into your site)?

Answer (score 1):

No, authentication is required to pull data directly from Google.  You could use one 'global' Google account and keep that account authenticated through code so that your users can access that data.

Only other option I've seen is to automate the export of the CSV data (via email) and have a routine that pulls off the CSV data and imports it into a system for public/private use - such as in your example.

Hope this helps!